# OVER Order Case based on custom columns and different data types

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL statement which is being used to page the results using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [tbl1].[Col1] ASC ) As RowNumber,
        [tbl1].[Col1],
        [tbl1].[Col2],
        [tbl1].[Col3],
        ( SELECT [tbl2].[Col1] 
          FROM [tbl2] 
          WHERE [tbl2].[id] = [tbl1].[id] 
                AND [tbl2].[subid] = 2 ) As theColumnName
    FROM
        [tbl1]
) As tbl
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

This all works fine and as expected. However I now want to introduce some additional `ORDER BY` functionality based on a value passed into the stored procedure.

So I have updated my `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY...` statement to

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'type1' THEN [tbl1].[Col1]
         WHEN @sortBy = 'type2' THEN [tbl1].[Col2]
    END,
    CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'type3' THEN [tbl1].[Col3]
    END
ASC) As RowNumber
```

As you can see here I have a `CASE` statement within the `OVER ()` method, and there are two `CASE`'s because `[Col3]` is a different data type than the other colums.

Now this works fine, but I cannot find out how to order by my column `theColumnName` as I just receive the error message `Invalid column name 'theColumnName'`.

```
WHEN @sortBy = 'type4' THEN theColumnName
```

I have even tried to use the column number, e.g. `WHEN @sortBy = 'type4' THEN 5` but this will not work either.

**Is there a way to Order By this custom column name?**

Comment: This one of those reasons that building the sql on the client can be a good idea. Even when you get this to work, how would you sort by a combination of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the subquery to the `from` clause, such as:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [tbl1].[Col1] ASC ) As RowNumber,
    [tbl1].[Col1],
    [tbl1].[Col2],
    [tbl1].[Col3],
    t2.col1 As theColumnName
FROM [tbl1] t join
     (select id, col1
      from tbl2
      where subid = 2
    ) t2
    on t.id = t2.id
```

Now, you will be able to include `t2.col1` in the `row_number() order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks using this helped me get to the solution. I had to change `Select id, col1 from...` to `Select id, col1 As theColumnName from...` because I actually have 3 of these which produce different results.